# PostgreSQL calculate percentage of current row's value over sum of totals

Tags: postgresql

I group my data by `seconditemid`. Is it possible to calculate each row's percentage of `sum(extcost)` over the total sum (all table data's extcost combined)?

for example we have 2 rows in the result set, A1 has total of 4500, A2 has total of 5500, the grand total should be 10000 and A1 occupies 45%, A2 occupies 55%.

```
seconditemid|ratio
--------------------
A1          |.45
--------------------
A2          |.55
```

My query is

```
select seconditemid,  
    round(100.0*(
        sum(case when seconditemid = ---the current row's seconditemid
        then 1 else 0 end)/sum(extcost)
    ),1) as ratio
from inventory_fact f inner join item_master_dim i using (itemmasterkey)
where transtypekey = 1
group by seconditemid
order by 2 desc;
```

That does not work. I tried creating a view first

```
create view v1 as(
    select sum(extcost) as sumExtcost from inventory_fact
);
```

and select from it

```
select seconditemid, round(100.0*(
        sum(extcost)/sum(v1.sumextcost)
    ),1) as ratio
from from inventory_fact f inner join item_master_dim i using (itemmasterkey), v1
where transtypekey = 1
group by seconditemid
order by 2 desc;
```

then the ration of each column becomes 0.

Comment: the 2d query seems fine, are you sure each item has >=10% of the value? You round up to the 1st digit after point only

Answer (score 3):

Let's take this sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE c (
    seconditemid text,
    total int
);

INSERT INTO c (seconditemid, total) VALUES ('A1', 4500);
INSERT INTO c (seconditemid, total) VALUES ('A2', 5500);
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT seconditemid, total, 
       total::float / (SUM(total) OVER()) as ratio
FROM c;
```

->

```
 seconditemid | total | ratio 
--------------+-------+-------
 A1           |  4500 |  0.45
 A2           |  5500 |  0.55
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second query should be ok but you got `0`s back because [integer division truncates the results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html). You'd need to cast your sum values to `float`s explicitly.

Here is an example without the view

```sql
SELECT g.seconditemid, g.extcost::float / t.total::float percent -- << here
  FROM (
  SELECT seconditemid, SUM(extcost) extcost
    FROM inventory_fact
   GROUP BY seconditemid
) g CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(extcost) total
    FROM inventory_fact
) t
 ORDER BY percent DESC
```

Output:

```
| seconditemid | percent |
|--------------|---------|
|           A2 |    0.55 |
|           A1 |    0.45 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4a256/1)